# Interchange limit-integral & Equivalency of sequence convergence and concrete convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, cauchy-integral-formula

I got stuck in the proof of Cauchy's Integral Formula for higher derivatives in *Stein's Complex Analysis, page 48*:

Under what Conditions over a function $f$, we can infer that :

> $\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_Cf(z,h)dz=\int_C\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(z,h)dz$

A Try :

$\displaystyle\left|\int_Cf(z,h)dz-\int_C\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(z,h)dz\right|\leq
P_C.\sup_{z\in C}\left|f(z,h)-\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(z,t)\right|$.

Now, I think there's a way to control right hand side, when $h$ would be small.

Comment: See the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) and the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: i dont know measure theory, but can a measure space defined on the complex field which is not an ordered set?
Our professor did this : He argued that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $e>0$ such that :
$$\forall h : |h|<e\Rightarrow\sup_{z\in C}|f(z,h)-L|<\epsilon$$
where $C$ is a small circle around $z$.
Then he said this convergence is uniform and hence u can interchange integral and limit !
but what does uniform convergence means here ?

Comment: @GitGud, Now I know measure theory. But, MCT & DCT talk about sequences of functions which is a discrete space of functions. Here we have a concrete limit "$h\rightarrow0$". Is this issue solvable ?

Comment: There's nothing that stops the MCT or DCT from working if you have a parameterized family of functions rather than a sequence of functions.  Those are definitely the results that are relevant to your question.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Could you explain how it's possible to consider parameterized family of functions or make it rigorous ?

Comment: Continuity vs sequential continuity?

Comment: You know, my problem is this : Let $f_h(x)$ for $h\in[0,1]$ be a collection of functions (can think $F(h,x)=f_h(x)$ as a multivariable function) and assume that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{\frac1n}(x)=g(x)$$
Now, can we infer that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}f_{h}(x)$ exists and equals $g(x)$ ?

Comment: Equality is easy, but what about existence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unhappy with MCT and DCT, your proof is correct. The control you need is *precisely* what is called uniform convergence.

---

With regards to your question in the comments,

> Proof of $\lim_{h→ 0} f(h) = L$ iff for every null sequence $a_n$, $\lim_{n→∞} f(a_n) = L$.

Clearly LHS implies RHS. Suppose that it is not true that  $\lim_{h→ 0} f(h) = L$. Then there is some $ε >0$ 
such that for every $\delta>0$, we can find a point $x<\delta$ such that $|f(x) - L| > ε $. Setting $\delta = 1/n$, we extract a null sequence $0<x_n<1/n$ of such points. Thus $f(x_n) \not→ L$.

This proof can be reused with almost no change for many 'limits', e.g. uniform limits of functions.

Comment: Yes, I knew it. But my problem is this : Let $f_h(x)$ for $h\in[0,1]$ and assume that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{\frac1n}(x)=g(x)$$
Now, can we infer that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}f_{h}(x)$ exists and equals $g(x)$ ?

Comment: No, but $\lim_{h→ 0 } f_h = g$ iff for every null sequence $a_n$, $\lim_{n→∞} f_{a_n} = g$.

Comment: It's a huge help for me if you give a proof or a hint to prove this assertion.
Or maybe it's better to ask it as a different question in Math.SE ?

Comment: @FardadPouran I have edited my answer :)

Comment: @FardadPouran and I have now edited it to now use standard symbols to avoid confusion. Forgive me :)

Comment: Well done. Thank you. You solved so many problems in my mind in Analysis :))

Comment: You're welcome :)